# How do I get the "Payback" achievement?

Tags: achievements, half-life-2, half-life-2-episode-two

In Half-Life 2 Episode Two there is a "Payback" achievement. Its description reads:

> Kill a Hunter with its own flechettes.

I have spent quite some time trying to get that achievement but I am not sure how to do it. I have tried to pick up the flechettes by hand or with the gravity gun. I have tried standing so that another Hunter shoots the Hunter I want to kill. I have tried hitting a Hunter with my car while its flechettes stuck to it but none of them got me the achievement.

Suddenly I received this achievement when I was throwing some stuff at a Hunter with the gravity gun killing it in the process. I have no idea why that happened, maybe there were flechettes attached to the stuff I was throwing at it.

What is the proper way to get the achievement? Are you really only supposed to throw stuff at the Hunter that happens to have some of this Hunter's flechettes stuck on it?

Comment: Can I ask why you re-tagged this with the general half-life-series tag?  That's not what it's for; it's for questions that span across the entire series.  Your question is limited specifically to an episode of Half Life 2.

Comment: @fbueckert Because that was how I understood the tagging scheme proposed at http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/reconsidering-how-we-tag-games-in-a-series/2585#2585 and also what I did with my other HL2EP2 question. I didn't want to exclusively tag is as half-life-2 as this is a sequel to HL2 and basically a separate game. Feel free to change this if I misinterpreted the linked answer.

Comment: Ah, I can see how you would interpret that.  A fair misunderstanding.  As I said, the -series tags are meant for questions that span across the games.  Since this question is specifically for Episode 2, it may warrant it's own tag, but it seems our actual tagging for this is inconsistent.  I suppose the current tag is as good as any until we can figure out some consistency.

Comment: It is a big mistake to place 3 separate games under one tag. No wonder it confuses people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way to get the achievement, is by using an object to shield yourself from the Hunter's flechettes, then using the stuck flechettes to kill the Hunter.

This is demonstrated in this video:

Throwing would have worked too, as shown in this next video (the quality is much lower and you can skip to 3:30)

When throwing, it is advised to use objects that have a low chance of killing Hunters when thrown. Using a barrel or tire is recommended over a radiator, for instance.

Comment: Cool, I had never realized that Hunters dissolve when you throw flechettes at them.

Answer (score 3):

It's the explosion of his own flechettes that must kill him so when you threw something at his face and got the achievement, it was because there were flechettes stuck to the object.

The easiest way to achieve it is to take a barrel with the gravity gun, wait for the hunter to attack you with flechettes, then run toward him with the barrel and wait for the flechettes to explode near him. Notice 2 things, you can get this achievement while you are dead (when the screen goes all red), you can hurt the hunter before with the shotgun and just finish him with his flechettes and still get the achievement.